# Emulator Zoomed In, Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently updated My AS to 3.1, Now i was excited about the quick boot feature. when i turned on my Emulator, it's running alright, but showing a red old designed device and already zoomed in.
How to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot ?

Comment: Thanks for responding , i deleted and re-created the virtual device,, seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the device and re-created from AVD manager.The problem was solved. I guess it was missing system images.